# NameError: name 'bls' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

My code below returns name error even though it works in a previous cell to fetch a different data set

```
wages = bls.get_series('CIU2020000000000A') 

wages.to_csv('bls_wages_data_csv')

df = pd.read_csv('bls_wages_data_csv') 

df.columns = 'Date', 'Wages'
df.head()
```

​

NameError: name 'bls' is not defined

Comment: Can you share the error traceback and have you defined bls somewhere?

Comment: Where is bls coming from? Need to see the rest of the script. This error occurs when you try to use an object that hasn't been defined/initialised yet. If you are following a tutorial make sure you have imported the library with the same name.

Comment: If you're working in a Jupyter notebook you need to make sure that if any variables are assigned in a previous cell, that you've actually run all previous cells in the current session, or else they won't be defined e.g. if you restart the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above never defines `bls`. You need something like `bls = pd.read_csv('bls.csv')`.

Since it ran before my guess is you have this somewhere in your code but you added this cell before you defined bls. Now that you have restarted your notebook you don't actually have bls defined when you make the call.

If the ordering isn't the issue, then you should check if the file for the bls data is in your working directory. You can go to your pwd and open the terminal then run ls or dir and see if your data is there.